# Delegate Call back method returns variable slow which causes variable nil while accessing from another class?

Tags: ios, swift, callback, delegates, cllocationmanager

In my app delegate class, i am trying to retrieve user Current Location from another class using delegate. This retreived User Curren location will be used in many parts of my application.So ,i have set it here in `AppDelegate` Class

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var helperLocation:HelperLocationManager?
    var currentLocation:CLLocation?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        //get the current location and set it so all other screens can use it
        self.helperLocation = HelperLocationManager()
        self.helperLocation?.delegate = self 
        return true
    }
}

   extension AppDelegate: SendLocationDelegate{

     func sendCoOrdinates(loccoordinate:CLLocation, placemark:CLPlacemark){
             currentLocation = loccoordinate
      }
    }
```

And this is what seems to be my `HelperLocationManager` Class

```
protocol SendLocationDelegate{

    func sendCoOrdinates(coordinates:CLLocation,placemark:CLPlacemark)

}

class HelperLocationManager: NSObject {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var delegate:SendLocationDelegate?

    override init() {

        super.init()

        var code = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        if code == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined {

            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        }

        locationManager.delegate = self

    }


}


extension HelperLocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate{


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        switch status {

        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:

            println( "Restricted Access to location")

        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:

            println( "User denied access to location please turn on the location")
            // UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
            //may be open here settings page and say to turn on the setting location services


        default:

            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        var locValue = locations.last as! CLLocation
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks,error)-> Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0 {

                let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                self.delegate?.sendCoOrdinates(locValue,placemark: pm)

            } else {

                println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })


    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

        println("Your error is ", error.localizedDescription)

    }

}
```

I made my call back method to trigger if there is any change in the user location...

Everything is fine. `HelperLocationManager` class sends the current location to the method `sendCoOrdinates`that is implemented in `AppDelegate` And I have set the current location and now i am accessing these location from `presentedViewController` as

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
 pickUpDistanceLocation = appDelegate.currentLocation
```

My problem is when i try to access the value very fast enough in another class during the time interval the delegate call back method doesnot send me my current Location.I get nil in this case.but if i wait 2-3 sec and go to another class i get the value from delegate.

*Can anyone explain me what am i doing wrong?*

Comment: So you can never access the location from your presentedViewController ? Or can you if you wait a few seconds ?

Comment: i can if i wait for some seconds....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an architectural issue - you say:

> when i try to access the value very fast enough in another class during the time interval the delegate call back method does not send me my current Location

You have to invert that - rather than checking the current location, with the risk of not having one because it's not been obtained yet, you should let the `HelperLocationManager` notify when it has a location (the hollywood principle: *don't call me, I'll call you*).

This can be done in different ways:

- using the delegation pattern
- using an event bus (which can be implemented with `NSNotificationCenter`)
- using callbacks

There are of course many other ways to achieve the same result.

The delegation pattern is probably not the best solution when there are more than one observer.

I would use the callback way, with a subscriber registering to location updates by providing a closure to `HelperLocationManager`.

`HelperLocationManager` can store all callbacks into an array, and invoke each of them when a location update is available. Optionally, it can invoke a closures right after registration, if a location is already available.

Last, the subscriber must be able to unsubscribe, so `HelperLocationManager` should expose a method which removes a callback from its internal list.

This is just an idea - as said, it can be done in several different ways, the common rule is to just invert how the location is passed.

Note: I would make `HelperLocationManager` a singleton, and remove it from `AppDelegate`. If I want to use `HelperLocationManager`, I should contact it directly, instead of having to access through a 3rd party (the app delegate).

Comment: Thank you antonio for your answer.....i change my code to Singleton pattern..and still the same..after testing i got this method didUpdateLocations of CLLocationManagerDelegate firing 4 times....??Is that i get location update value late...And i used this  var locValue = locations.last as! CLLocation to get the latest value?

Comment: Making it a singleton doesn't solve the problem - you have to invert the way the location is read: rather than your code reading the `HelperLocationManager` property, you have to make `HelperLocationManager` tell your code when a location is available

Comment: what if user tried to navigate to another view controller and the notification pattern still dont send value to observer..may be i should show a activity indicator then ?

Comment: yeah that would be good - even a message saying "obtaining location", if pertinent - that depends on what you have to do and how much important having the location is

Comment: i just want to show the loading for my last option???is there really some kind of way not to do that? because i think neither of these design pattern fit into my problem? and i have got a thinking to show the loading message? sorry to ask once again

Comment: IMO the way it should work is: your VC registers for a location update, then it shows a waiting message - the manager, as soon as obtains a location (or an error happens), forwards it to the VC. At that point the VC hides the waiting message, and "consume" the location